# Trouble adding checkboxes to HTML div using JS

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

As a noob at programming, I'm having some HTML/JS pHroblems. I'm trying to make a dynamic checkbox list where you can add tasks to complete. I've done my research, combing through at least 10 websites, and for some reason, nothing seems to be working. I can't find anything in the code, and I've tried multiple approaches.
HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>To-Do List
</title>
<link href="Main Page Styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainJavascript.js"></script>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/aladin:n4:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <p>To-Do List</p>
</header>
<input type="text" id = "checkboxName">
<input type="submit" value="Add New Task" onClick="addTask()" id = "taskAdder">
<div id="toBeDone"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var addTask = function () {

    /*var newCheckBox = document.createElement('input');
    var checkboxText = document.getElementById("checkboxName").value;
    newCheckBox.type = 'checkbox';
    newCheckBox.value = (checkboxText + '<br/>');

    var parentElement = document.getElementById("toBeDone");
    parentElement.appendChild(newCheckBox);*/



    /*var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
    newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
    var checkboxTextNode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("checkBoxName").value);
    newCheckbox.appendChild(checkboxTextNode);

    document.getElementById("toBeDone").appendChild(newCheckbox);*/

    var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.value = document.getElementById("checkboxName").value;
    document.getElementById("toBeDone").appendChild(newCheckbox);

    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.htmlFor = document.getElementById("checkboxName").value;
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("checkboxName").value));

    document.getElementById("toBeDone").appendChild(label);
    document.getElementById("toBeDone").appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

Comment: It is better if you make up html & insert it using the script instead of setting everything manually like createElement, checkbox.type, value etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the variable `newCheckbox` when you create the element and append it to the DIV, but `checkbox` when you set the type and value.

```
var newCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
newCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
newCheckbox.value = document.getElementById("checkboxName").value;
document.getElementById("toBeDone").appendChild(newCheckbox);
```

Your labels aren't working because the `for` attribute has to match the `id` of the checkbox, and you never give your checkboxes `id`s. It would be better if you simply wrapped the label around the checkbox, so the resulting HTML looks like:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="whatever">whatever</label>
```

I'll leave this as an exercise for you.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Aq8eS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you are using the submit type input.

when you click on submit button page reload will occur and you cant see the result of your javascript code

use a button instead

```
<input type="button" value="Add New Task" onClick="addTask()" id = "taskAdder">
```

Comment: It doesn't reload if it's not in a `<form>`.